# How to send buttons in whatsapp-web.js?

Tags: node.js, whatsapp

I want to send buttons using whatsapp-web.js.
I have already send list in android system.
But I can't send buttons in both android and iOS.
https://github.com/pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js is not working well.

I tried to find solution but I think there is a problem in node modules.